# Perl Regex How to capture two patterns between groups

Tags: regex, grep, pcre

I need to match a line ONLY if it starts with the @ symbol and also contains a single 'A' character, not in a string with other characters. Just the @ and the A need, not SOA for example. Trying to this with grep -P method.

Zone file fragment:

```
@            IN     SOA     some.bogus.com hostmaster.bogus.com. (
@            IN     A       12.34.56.789
             IN     A       012.345.678.9
@     1800   IN     AAAA    789237:mou68:028n:0000:8afn:
@            IN     NS      ns500.mydummy.server.
@            IN     TXT     "v=spf1 mx ~all"
```

Using `grep -P "(^|\s)\K@(?=\s|$)" myzonefile.com` get the lines with @ symbol just fine, but how do I modify it to get the lines with the @ symbol AND with a single 'A' character?

This `grep -P '(?=.*@)(?=.*A)' myzonefile.com` gets the second line, which is correct, but also gets the SOA line, which I do not want.

This `grep -E '\b[A]\s' myzonefile.com` gets all lines with single 'A' character only but I have been unable to include an AND operation to also match the @ sign too without piping to another grep. SO not an option.

Should I use sed or awk for this, better suited?

Comment: A line begins with `'@'` and contains exactly one `'A'` if it is matched by the regular expression `^@[^A\r\n]*A[^A\r\n]*$` with flags m ("multiline": '^' and '$' are beginning of-line and end-of-line anchors, respectively) and g ("global": do not return after first match) set. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/4lzrlV/1). The expression reads, "Match '@' at the beginning of the string followed by zero or more characters other than 'A' and line terminators, followed by 'A', followed by zero or more characters other than 'A' and line terminators at the end of the string".

Comment: @CarySwoveland How can I go about accounting for something like the 3rd line? Such as, nothing but whitespace before the first field, or characters are encountered, and then the A after that? The reason for this would be to remove any line that starts with '@' and has an exact 'A', or any line that starts with whitespace and has an exact 'A'.  
 Something like `awk '$1 !~ /^\s*I/ || $2!="A"' myzonefile.com , but  with grep -P.

Comment: I revised my post. I need to not have a match unless the A and @ are isolated characters, not mixed into a string.

Comment: Your first sentence is clear, that you wish to match lines that begin with `'@'` and contain exactly one `'A'` that is preceded and followed by a whitespace. (I assume `'A'` cannot be at the end of the line.) According to that only the second line in your example is to be matched. Do you also wish to match the third line in your example? If so you need to edit the question to clarify the requirement and also indicate which line(s) in your example are to be matched, and why.

Answer (score 1):

With `grep` and word boundaries (`\b`):

```
grep '^@.*\bA\b' myzonefile.com
```

or

```
sed -n '/^@.*\bA\b/p' myzonefile.com
```

Output:

```
@            IN     A       12.34.56.789
```

See: [The Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/3776858)

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -P '(^|\s)\K@(?=\s).*?\sA\s' myzonefile.com
```

Comment: If you do not mind, can you explain why you are using both the * and the ? before the last pattern? Reading the docs, I get `.   Match any single character except newline`  , `*   Matches the preceding element 0 or more times` , and `?   Matches the preceding element 0 or 1 times`.

Comment: `X*?` is like `X*`, but the former makes the match as short is possible. It's useful if you add `+(\S+)` to the regexp. By using the `?`, it will find the very first viable `A` rather than the last one.

Comment: Your regex matches the lines `"     @       IN     A       12.34.56.789"`, `"@            IN     A A     12.34.56.789"` and `"@            AN     A       12.34.56.789"`. Is that intended? Note that in the first  of these strings `(^|\s)` matches the last space preceding `'@'`

Comment: Only @humbleStrength can say what is intended or them. My regexp is a working solution for the first sentence of the question. It can be fine-tuned for more specific requirements.

Comment: The zone file syntax will not allow the other cases mentioned by Cary as I am executing some integrity checks on the files to ensure no formatting blunders. However, thanks for pointing that out in case something does slip by and the lines are not entered correctly, as depicted in the examples Cary showed.

Answer (score 0):

u mean like this ?

```
echo '
@            IN     SOA     some.bogus.com hostmaster.bogus.com. (
@            IN     A       12.34.56.789
             IN     A       012.345.678.9
@     1800   IN     AAAA    789237:mou68:028n:0000:8afn:
@            IN     NS      ns500.mydummy.server.
@            IN     TXT     "v=spf1 mx ~all"' |
```

---

```
mawk '$1$2 == "@A"' FS='([ \t]+[0-9]*[ \t]+IN)?[ \t]+'
```

---

```
@            IN     A       12.34.56.789
```

Answer (score 0):

- Using a single 'A' as field separator `-F' A '`
- Looking for rows that start with '@'  `/^@/` and have two fields `NF==2`

---

```
$ awk -F' A ' '/^@/ && NF==2' file
@            IN     A       12.34.56.789
```